Does CDF must have value 0 at lowest possible input?
Suppose $F$ is the CDF of a real valued random variable. I know that $F(- \infty) = 0$, because the RV cannot take a value less than that.
But I was thinking of an RV whose value for sure comes from, say, $[0, 1]$. Is it necessary that $F(0)$ be 0? More specifically, can I have some sort of a "point mass" at $x = 0$, so that the CDF is zero for $x < 0$, some number $k \in (0, 1)$ at 0 and then is continuous till it reaches 1 before or at 1?
What would be the associated PDF? I imagining a form like this:  $\delta(x) + f(x)$, with $\delta$ being the Dirac-delta function. But how do I specify the exact value of $k$ on a PDF formulation? Is this even correct?

Why does there have to be a PDF? $//$ How do you define a PDF?

Doesnt have to be, just wanted to know if it's possible

What does the "CSF" in your title mean?

Was a typo, should've been CDF. Edited it, thanks for pointing out

Again, concerning the title: there is no "lowest possible input," because by definition the CDF is defined for all real numbers.  I think you might be trying to refer to the support of the distribution. // Notice, too, that the function $G(x,\alpha)= F(\alpha + (1-\alpha)x)$ is also a CDF for $0\lt \alpha\lt 1$ with support in $[0,1].$ If you can conclude $F(0)=0$ then you can conclude $F(\alpha)=G(0)=0$ for all such $\alpha.$  That wouldn't make any sense, would it?

One of the criticisms of the Hogg and Craig book is that they provide treatments for scenarios like this. I consider it trivial like most. But consider a degenerate random variable taking value 0 with probability 1. You can write the CDF as the Heaviside function defined for all real values and this is WLOG the same as the CDF written as F(x) = 1 if x=0 for a singular support/event space {0}.

@AdamO I believe there's a universally understood definition for the CDF of a real-valued random variable $X$ and it's independent of the support or "event space;" namely, it's the function assigning to any real number $x$ the quantity $\Pr(X\le x).$  (There is a varying convention concerning whether the defining event is $X\le x,$ $X\lt x,$ or even $X\ge x$ or $X\gt x,$ but in every case the domain of the CDF is still $\mathbb R.$)

@whuber I think you are saying better what I was trying to express - I was moreover trying to chuckle at my own experience learning this. I think a great reference on this is McDonald and Weiss' "Real Anaylsis" text, Ch. 5. They establish elemental measure theory first, so that the probability axioms can be stated briefly and left at that.

Consider the following probability function as an example:
$$f(x) = \left\{
  \begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    0.2, & \text{if}\ x=0, \\
    0.8 \cdot \beta(x;\alpha,\beta), & 0 < x < 1
  \end{array}\right.$$
Here we have a probability mass of $0.2$ at $x=0$, i.e., the probability of seeing $x=0$ equals $0.2$.  With (the remaining) probability $0.8$, $x \neq 0$; in this case, $x \sim \beta(\alpha,\beta)$, a Beta distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
If we wanted to write this out in purely mathematical notation, we could use the indicator function $1(a)$, which equals $1$ if $a$ is true and $0$ otherwise:
$$f(x) = 0.2\cdot 1(x=0) + 0.8 \cdot \beta(x;\alpha,\beta)(1-1(x=0))$$
The cumulative distribution function would clearly be:
$$F(x) =   \left\{\begin{array}{@{}ll@{}}
    0, &  x<0, \\
0.2 + 0.8\cdot F_\beta(x;\alpha,\beta), &0 \leq x < 1 \\
    1, & 1 \leq x\\
  \end{array}\right.
$$
where $F_\beta(\cdot;\cdot)$ is the cumulative density function of the Beta distribution.
